# Deploying my current installation of Ubuntu to all the computers in my lab

Tags: system-installation, live-usb, disk-image

I've been looking through countless answers, but haven't been able to find a solution which exactly outlines what I'm trying to do. It seems like Clonezilla is the closest, or `dd`. Here's what I'm trying to do:

- The current installation I have of Ubuntu has lots of software installed and settings configured
- I have 25 (hardware identical) computers in my lab, and would like them all to boot this exact same image of my operating system
- I thought there would be a way for me to copy an image of my operating system to a live USB, and boot/install from it to the other computers in my lab
- I'm open to a more scalable option as well, which allows all the computers to stay up to date and in-sync (i.e. if I install a new software package on my main computer, somehow it will be deployed to all 25 computers in the lab also)

I know this is a very open ended question, but can anyone share some insight? Thank you.

Comment: Try something like https://fogproject.org/ for the initial installation and Puppet for the post-install syncing.

Comment: @muru Thanks, looking into both. Puppet definitely looks interesting. Thinking that it may be easier to just install clean versions of the OS on all machines, and only use Puppet to automate installations and all.

Comment: My old setup started as Puppet-only; then we switched to fog+puppet - since we had to do an install anyway, it made sense to get as much as possible on the system from the start (including Puppet itself, for one). We'd regularly update the image using a system on which Puppet was running. After that it was pretty simple: boot system to network, wait for installation, set hostname, reboot.